# Formatar Variável Int em moeda R$ no Android

Tags: android, textview

Utilizo a lib Maskformatter para formatar campos Edittext. Porém agora estou recebendo um valor de uma variável int e queria formatar ela no valor moeda R$.

Exemplo: na variavel contendo 1000
Formatar: 10,00

Usando a lib não consigo pois ele só aceita EditText.

Estou usando o resultado dessa variável e exibindo em um TextView.

Comment: Uma variável contendo 1000 (mil) o correto seria formatar: R$ 1000,00 né?

Comment: @Laerte como no exemplo, vamos supor que na variável o valor deu  trinta e quatro reais. Porém no meu textview ele está exibindo 3400. Formatando gostaria que ele colocasse a vírgula, ficando 34,00.

Answer (score 0):

Bom consegui resolver depois de uma boa lida

Usei

`NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();`

e na variável do TextView

`nf.format(valortotal / 100)`

resultado no que eu queria mesmo `R$34,00 ou R$10,00`

Pelo que entendi usando o `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` ele pega a formatação do sistema, seja ele BR ou EN.